# Wine - not showing content of windows

Tags: wine

Today I switched from Windows to Ubuntu, so I am a beginner.

Few years ago I started to use a Windows program to generate invoices, so I got a lot of invoices in my archive and I need to continue using this program on Ubuntu.

So I installed Wine on my Ubuntu and then my invoice generator too. Everything is working fine, program loads correctly. BUT: The problem is that the text does not show in windows.

Take a look at this screenshot (in this dialogue should be a text asking license key):
http://i44.tinypic.com/2v3076o.png

Does anybody have some experience with this? What should I install or configure?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Can't see the picture linked too. It just leads to a forum in a different language where I assume I have to register for.

Comment: Sorry, screenshot is here: http://i44.tinypic.com/2v3076o.png

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [Wine AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/) for your application? Others will sometimes post instructions to get an application working. Of course, the less of a userbase your application has, the less odds that someone else has looked at this.

Also, try to run the wine app from the command line, wine will very often print out possible clues and errors that you can search the internet for. Perhaps there are other applications with similar errors that others have solved for.

Comment: Thank you, but my app is not in AppDB.
There were no outputs in Terminal too. :(